# Unable to calibrate LiDAR with Camera

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, calibration, lidar, opencv-solvepnp

I am trying to calibrate my LiDAR with my camera. I initially tried the Matlab LiDAR-Camera calibrator app to perform calibration, but when I projected the LiDAR points back  onto the image, they did not line up.

Assuming something was incorrect with the initial calibration, I manually selected the calibration points in both Image and 3D point cloud as shown in the images.

[image: Calibration points in Image]

[image: Calibration points in Point cloud]

```
bool calibration = cv::solvePnP(ptCldObjectPtsPOI,
                                    imgObjectPtsPOI,
                                    K,
                                    d,
                                    R,
                                    T,
                                    true,
                                    cv::SOLVEPNP_EPNP);
```

I am able to get an transformation, but when I use this transformation to project the LiDAR points back on the image, the LiDAR point doesn't overlap correctly.

[image: LiDAR Image Overlap]

I use the following code to apply transform to the 3D points

```
def applyTransformation(points, tranformation):

    assert tranformation.shape[0] == 4
    assert tranformation.shape[1] == 4
    assert points.shape[0] == 3

    points = np.dot(tranformation[:3,:3], points)

    for i in range(3):
        points[i,:] = points[i,:] + tranformation [i,3]

    return points
```

and use the following code to project the 3D point into image frame

```
def projectPointsToCamFrame(points, K):
    assert K.shape[0] <= 4
    assert K.shape[1] <= 4
    assert points.shape[0] == 3

    depth = points[2,:]
    
    # convert K into projection Matrix
    P = np.eye(4)
    P[0:K.shape[0],0:K.shape[1]] = K

    # Concatinate 1s to 4th layer
    points = np.concatenate((points,np.ones((1,points.shape[1]))))
    
    points = np.dot(P,points)
    points = points[:3,:]

    # Normalize the points

    points = points/points[2:3, :].repeat(3, 0).reshape(3, points.shape[1]) #These points are in camera co-ordinates
    return points
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.